# Where to store User object using MVVM and Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I am having trouble figuring out where to put User object so it can be accessed throughout the app (any fragment/activity) since it holds all data app needs. My goal is not to store the user object locally so DataStore or SharedPreferences is not what I'm looking for.

How it is currently:

- I have authenticator class which is injected into authentication ViewModel using Hilt. LogIn / SignUp functions return User object which I store inside the ViewModel. I see this is wrong as ViewModel should contain only data needed for a certain screen.
  However, I see no other way where I can fetch user model once on app start and allow it to be accessed by all ViewModels.

Problem here is also that I cannot share this authentication ViewModel between multiple activities.

What is best way to handle this?

Ideally I would like it to work like this (but feel free to suggest more proper way):

- App start / Sign Up / Log In - create User data object, its stored somewhere and is not refetched unless app is fully restarted
- All viewmodels can access this object and then I would use parts of it for example "ProfileActivity" would show user's name and email while "HomeActivity" would should user's blog posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you don't require it to persist through a full app restart(not recommended but that's not the question) all you need is `@Singleton` that will be managing all of it.

This is not full code but it illustrates the principle.

```
@Singleton
class AuthManager @Inject constructor() {

    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<AuthManagerState> = MutableStateFlow(AuthManagerState.NotLoggedIn)
    val state: StateFlow<AuthManagerState> = _state.asStateFlow()

    suspend fun logIn() {
        _state.value = AuthManagerState.LogggingIn
        delay(500)
        _state.value = AuthManagerState.LoggedIn(user = User(firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe"))
    }
}

data class User(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String
)

sealed class AuthManagerState {
    object NotLoggedIn: AuthManagerState()
    object LogggingIn: AuthManagerState()
    data class LoggedIn(
        val user: User
    ): AuthManagerState()
}

@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(private val authManager: AuthManager): ViewModel() {

    val loggedInUserName: StateFlow<String?> = authManager.state.map {
        when(it) {
            is AuthManagerState.LoggedIn -> it.user.firstName
            AuthManagerState.LogggingIn -> null
            AuthManagerState.NotLoggedIn -> null
        }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), null)

    fun logIn() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            authManager.logIn()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to be what I want to do. Is this common way of doing it? What is the best practice regardless of my specific case. Like how would you do it in case where all data you need is inside User object and you need that object accessible to multiple ViewModels?

Comment: @DjoMan More or less yes, I think you can find a lot of examples that use this type of construct. In most general sense, I would do I this way. P.S. Funny to find you here after the reddit post